# How to determine how many elements of a cell arrary contain a specific cell

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

I have a cell 4x1,

```
{{1,2,3};{2,3};{1,2,3};{2,3}}
```

How can I found out, which cells contain `{2,3}`

i.e. `[0,1,0,1]` for the above example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way why are you using a cell of cells and not a cell of arrays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cellfun` and `isequal`:

```
cellfun(@(x)isequal({2,3},x),yourcell)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `aa =  {{1,2,3};{2,3};{1,2,3};{2,3}}`

You can use a for loop and store the results...

```
for jj = 1:4
    correct(jj) = isequal(aa{jj}, [2 3])
end
```